# MVC delete table field, but model.edmx not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm doing some testing, and I deleted a field from a table in my database, and tried to go update model from database, and the field is still in the .edmx file as well as .tt.   Shouldn't this update the model, when I do this by removing the field I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double click on your Entity Model to get it's context and delete the object.  Or you can right click in the blank space and select 'view Model Browser', Open up the 'Entity Types' and delete it there if you have a huge surface of many objects. The Entity Model is an extension of the database and will not auto update changes.

The Update function to my knowledge will look for changes added and refresh will update existing, but I am not certain if it will remove them.  You need to delete it by selecting the object and hitting delete.  Then running 'Custom Tool' on your t4 template to update from the template of your entity data model.  I am not certain with Entity version five which I BELIEVE is out with .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 if you need to update the t4 directly though.  It may due that.  But prior to that you need to hit the delete from what I have seen.

That is from my experience anyways with using Entity Framework to work with similar things on an MVVM model structure with WPF and using the t4 generation as POCO model classes.